# NameError: name 'April' is not defined

Tags: python

I know it is something stupid but I cannot figure out why it does not work.  Please help.

```
def main():
    yourAge=getAge() #get subject's age
    yourWeight=getWeight() #get subject's weight 
    yourBirthMonth=getMonth() #get subject's birth month
    correctAnswers(getAge, getWeight, getMonth)

def getAge():
    yourAge=input('Enter your age. ')
    return yourAge

def getWeight():
    yourWeight=input('Enter your weight.')
    return yourWeight

def getMonth():
    yourBirthMonth=input('Enter your birth month. ')
    return yourBirthMonth

def correctAnswers(getAge, getWeight, getMonth):
    if getAge <= 25:
        print'Congratulations, age is less than 25.'

    if getWeight >= 128:
        print'Congratulations, weight is more than 128.'

    if getMonth == 'April':
        print'Congratulations, month is April.'

main()
```

The traceback:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Beth/Documents/jeff/prog/lab 03/lab 3-5.py", line 35, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Beth/Documents/jeff/prog/lab 03/lab 3-5.py", line 10, in main
    yourBirthMonth=getMonth()#get subject's birth month
  File "C:/Users/Beth/Documents/jeff/prog/lab 03/lab 3-5.py", line 22, in getMonth
    yourBirthMonth=input('Enter your birth month. ')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'April' is not defined
```

Comment: Is this python 2.7 or 3.x?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`raw_input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input), not `input()`; the latter tries to interpret text input as Python code.

Typing `April` is interpreted as a variable name in that case. You could enter `"April"` instead but it's better to just not use `input()` here.

Answer (score 1):

In python2 `input` evaluates the input. Use `raw_input` to get unevaluated strings.

In your case `input` tries to lookup the variable `april` once you enter it, which for sure does not exist.

To visualize the effect, try entering `1/0` when promted for the age.

---

Basically your functions could look like this:

```
def getAge():
    return int(raw_input('Enter your age. '))

def getWeight():
    return int(raw_input('Enter your weight. '))

def getMonth():
    return raw_input('Enter your birth month. ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
yourBirthMonth=input('Enter your birth month. ')
```

To

```
yourBirthMonth=raw_input('Enter your birth month. ')
```

In Python 2, raw_input() returns a string, and input() tries to run the input as a Python expression